# response bad request in http request with php

Tags: php, laravel, rest

When i try to send a http request it return me a status 400 (Bad request , invalid headers)
the API require an access token and Content Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
this is my code :
the access token is very long
please help me

```
$response = Http::contentType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            ->withToken($access_token)
            ->timeout('2000')
            ->get('https://example /.../...',[
            ]);`
```

Answer (score 1):

use `withHeaders()` ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#headers

```php
$response = Http::withHeaders(["Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"])
    ->withToken($access_token)
    ->timeout('2000')
    ->get('https://example /.../...',[
    ]);`
```